# C# port_DataReceived doesn't work correctly

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I have an arduino & c# project. I have a `port_DataReceived` listener. In normally, It works correctly. But whenever I close `serialPort1` and open it again, it gives me an error.

Here is the listener:

```
void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (connect)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (10000 * serialPort1.BytesToRead) / serialPort1.BaudRate; i++);
        //Delay a bit for the serial to catch up
        String comingValue = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine(comingValue); 
        String rslt = comingValue[0].ToString(); // This line give me an error
    }
}
```

Here is the Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException'
>   occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

I am checking the `comingValue` both times it is `11`. first time it works but second time it doesn't work. I don't know why. If somebody know why, please help me. Thanks.

Comment: That for() loop is pointless, just delete it.  You are not paying attention to the e.EventType property.  And can therefore not assume that ReadExisting() always returns a non-empty string.  Simply checking the string's Length property covers all bases, even a screwy driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the string `IsNullOrEmpty()`. You're trying to read the first character by index. When there is not data in the `comingValue`. You'll get an index out of bounds.  Only read the first char when there is actually one (or more)

```
String comingValue = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
Console.WriteLine(comingValue); 
String rslt = "";
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comingValue))
    rslt = comingValue[0].ToString();
```

---

This is a bad practice thingy to use for a delay...

```
for (int i = 0; i < (10000 * serialPort1.BytesToRead) / serialPort1.BaudRate; i++);
```

This will run different on other computers. Try `Thread.Sleep(10);` or something.

Comment: But this line works an I can see the output:

        Console.WriteLine(comingValue);